# Android -> I want my textView hidden by Keyboard in activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

What I want is the opposite as everybody, I want to have a text view with some text in the bottom of my activity. With this code it looks okei:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/chkMinusvalia"
    android:text="Desliza hacia la derecha para ver la lista de bancos >>"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FFA500"
    android:textStyle="italic" />
```

The problem is that when the keyboard appears, the textView aligns to the top of the keyboard (the new parent bottom) covering other elements of the view... I would like that my textView keeps hidden under the keyboard

I guess it's simple, but I can't get to the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the manifestfile of your activity, set android:windowSoftInputMode to adjustPan

```
<activity
    android:name="zzz"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly! And also solved a problem I was having with the keyboard appearing automatically when starting the activity. 
Thanks a lot!